# What are the expected residual standard deviations from each of the fitted models and data-generating process?

Tags: mixed-model, expected-value, standard-deviation, simulation

I simulate data to be analyzed using a linear mixed-effects model. It is based on an experiment with 2 levels (`A` and `B`) of a single factor (`treatment`). There are a total of `n` experimental units, half in each factor level. There are `m` observations per experimental unit. In total, I have `N = n*m` observations.

When I analyze such data using `lmer(outcome~1+treatment+(1|exp.unit), data = original.data)`, I expect the residuals standard deviation to be equal to the standard deviation between observations within experimental units (`sd.w`). I believe this reasoning is correct, as the sampling distribution of the residuals standard deviation is centered on `sd.w`. It also makes sense because the variability between experimental units (`sd.b`) is captured by the random intercept (`1|exp.unit`), leaving only the variability from `sd.w` to be captured by the error term. *At least, this is how I see it.* **Question 1: Are my reasoning and my expectation that residuals SD in this case equals `sd.w` correct?**

After using a mixed model, I analyze the same dataset using a simple linear model `lm(outcome~1+treatment, data = original.data)`, which I know is not appropriate (it leads to pseudoreplication as defined by [Hurlbert](https://doi.org/10.2307/1942661) in 1984). I build a histogram of the sampling distribution of residuals standard deviations (see middle plot). I this case I'm not sure if I can (and how to) obtain the expected residuals standard deviation using the values I set for the simulation (e.g., `n`, `m`, `sd.b`, `sd.w`, ...). **Question 2: If possible in this case, how could I obtain the expected residuals SD independently from the simulation results? I want to add this value to the histogram as a vertical red line. Any guidance on this is appreciated!**

I use another simple linear model on the data averaged over experimental units `lm(outcome~1+treatment, data = averaged.data)`. In this case, I believe I can obtain the expected residuals standard deviation by calculating `sqrt(sd.b*sd.b + sd.w*sd.w/m)`. My reasoning is that the variability in residuals comes from the variability of averaging each group of `m` observations per experimental unit (`sd.w*sd.w/m`) plus the variability between experimental units (`sd.b*sd.b`). **Question 3: Are my reasoning and my expected residuals SD correct?**

```
library(lmerTest)

n = 10 # number of experimental units (half in each treatment)
m = 3 # number of observations per exp. unit
N = n*m # must be even number
sd.b = 10 # sd between experimental units
sd.w = 2 # sd between observation within experimental units
expected.mixed.model.sigma = sd.w # what I expect residual sd from mixed model to be
expected.averaged.model.sigma = sqrt(sd.b*sd.b + sd.w*sd.w/m) # what I expect residual sd from averaged model to be

exp.unit = as.factor(rep(1:n, each = m))
treatment = as.factor((rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = N/2)))


simulation = function(){
  random.intercept = rep(rnorm(n, 0, sd.b), each = m)
  error = rnorm(N, 0, sd.w)
  outcome = random.intercept + error
  
  # build data frame
  original.data = data.frame(outcome,
                             exp.unit,
                             treatment)
  
  # average over experimental units
  averaged.data = aggregate(outcome~treatment+exp.unit, data = original.data, FUN = mean)
  
  # linear mixed-effects model
  original.data.mixed.model = lmer(outcome~1+treatment+(1|exp.unit), data = original.data)
  # simple linear model (original data; same as mixed model)
  original.data.simple.model = lm(outcome~1+treatment, data = original.data)
  # simple linear model (averaged data)
  averaged.data.simple.model = lm(outcome~1+treatment, data = averaged.data)
  
  # collect residual standard deviation from each model
  mixed.model.sigma = sigma(original.data.mixed.model)
  original.data.simple.model.sigma = sigma(original.data.simple.model)
  averaged.data.simple.model.sigma = sigma(averaged.data.simple.model) 

  return(c(mixed.model.sigma,
           original.data.simple.model.sigma,
           averaged.data.simple.model.sigma))
}

set.seed(100)
x = replicate(1000, simulation())

par(mfrow = c(3,1)) # three plots on a 3 rows by 1 column grid
hist(x[1,], xlab = "mixed model residual sd", main = "red line is what I expect")
abline(v = expected.mixed.model.sigma, col = "red", lwd = 3)
hist(x[2,], xlab = "simple model residual sd", main = "not sure what to expect")
hist(x[3,], xlab = "averaged model residual sd", main = "red line is what I expect")
abline(v = expected.averaged.model.sigma, col = "red", lwd = 3)
```

Plot generated by the code above:
[image: histogram of residuals sd]